# sigma.js within ASP.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, sigma.js

I have a problem with sigmaJS. I would like to use one of the example files, e.g. filter.html within an ASPX website.

as soon as I put the example code (filter.html) in an aspx file and put the line:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="whatever.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="whatever" title="Sigma within ASPX" Debug="true" %>
```

on top, sigma.js does not render anymore.

Does anybody know help?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What is filter.html?

Comment: just one of these examples:
https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/examples

how to embed them in an aspx site?